# How to test React Material UI Drawer Component attribute value in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, cypress, e2e-testing

Given this MUI implementation within my react component:

```
 <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Drawer
        name="permDrawer"
        open={openSideDrawer}
        style={{ zIndex: -1000 }}
        variant="permanent"
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Box>
          <List
            sx={{
              [`& .active, & .${listItemClasses.root}:hover`]: {
                color: '#2196f3',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '30'
              }
            }}
          >
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                  paddingLeft: open ? 1 : 5
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeOutlined />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" sx={{ opeacity: open ? 0 : 1 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Box>
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
```

Im trying to test if the Drawer opens or not and I can successfully fire the click event and I see the expected behavior in my Cypress Test Runner. However I want to check the open attribute of the Drawer component as it changes from false to true because this is a more accurate test. But I am not able to get access to the open attribute  given :

```
describe('When testing sideMenu', () => {
    
it('it should open sideMenu', () => {
  cy.readFile('./secrets/swb-shell/cypress-e2e.json').then((testConfig) => {
    cy.visit('/')

    cy.get('[data-automation-id="uname"]').type(testConfig.users[0].userid, { log: false })
    cy.get('[data-automation-id="pwd"]').type(testConfig.users[0].password, { log: false })
    cy.get('[data-automation-id="loginBtn"]').click()

    cy.get('[name="permDrawer"]').should('have.attr','open','false');
    cy.get('.MuiToolbar-root > :nth-child(1) > .MuiButtonBase-root').click()
    cy.get('.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root').should('be.visible');
 

  })
})
```

})

As I understand it MUI obfuscates the markup and it is recommended to use additional libraries in order to properly test. Am I missing a dependency in my testing or is there another way I should go about this? This is my first time testing within cypress and I havent worked with react in 3 years so Id really appreciate some context and help! Ty !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the `open` attribute in the source is not present in the page at runtime.

You might try this to be "symmetrical"

```js
cy.get('.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root').should('be.not.visible');
cy.get('.MuiToolbar-root > :nth-child(1) > .MuiButtonBase-root').click()
cy.get('.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root').should('be.visible');
```

but I think the drawer is actually added/removed rather than made visible/invisible, so

```js
cy.get('.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root').should('not.exist');
cy.get('.MuiToolbar-root > :nth-child(1) > .MuiButtonBase-root').click()
cy.get('.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root').should('be.visible');  // existence is implied
```

---

**Checking `openSideDrawer`**

You can add your own attribute for `openSideDrawer`

```html
<Drawer
  name="permDrawer"
  open={openSideDrawer}
  data-cy-open={openSideDrawer}
```

```js
cy.get('[name="permDrawer"]').should('have.attr','data-cy-open','false');
```

Comment: I wrote a passing test in the light of your method because drawer property is always visible even if just collapsed by default. I had to check for a text element rendered within the drawer after it expanded. To me this is less than ideal because it would be nice to access the prop values. Thank you for the help! I can move forward for the time being.